# CAKEPHP Routing domain.com/s?searchFld=xxxx to domain.com/s/searchFld/xxxx

Tags: php, cakephp

I am running `cakephp 2.4.6` and my search results page url is `www.domain.com/s?searchFld=xxxx`.

I do not want to use `301/30 htaccess` redirect because I read that using special characters may affect SEO and SERP CTR rate, as users tend to avoid clicking URLs with special characters.

So where in `cakephp` can I change the search result from `www.domain.com/s?searchFld=xxxx` to `www.domain.com/search/xxxx`

Here is the `routes.php` file, so how can I fix that in `routers.php`

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));

CakePlugin::routes();

require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Comment: I suppose that everything about the routing is clearly described in the documentation.

Comment: Stanislav, I have read the documentation and I could not find my answer, that's why I am here. Please do not come up with any assumptions.

Comment: Ok, then have a look at this again please. Everything is clearly explained in this section of the docs. You just need to connect /search/* to some controller and action. All your xxxx will become parameters for that action. https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#connecting-routes Hope it helps.